# Popup window grabs focus even when WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus has been set

Tags: qt, pyqt, popup, qt5, pyqt5

We have a custom-made [`Qt.Popup`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) Window in our PyQt5 application where we have also set the `WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus` flag

```
WINDOW_FLAGS = (
    QtCore.Qt.Popup
    | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
    | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    | QtCore.Qt.WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus
)

class BreathingNotification(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, WINDOW_FLAGS)
```

The problem we have is that the popup window grabs input focus when shown

If we change `Qt.Popup` to `Qt.Dialog` we don't have a problem with the focus any longer, but instead we will see the dialog/window in the taskbar, which we'd like to avoid

Grateful for help with this problem!

Comment: Have you tried `Qt.BypassWindowManagerHint`?

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you, using this with `Qt.Dialog` removes the window/dialog from the taskbar! `Qt.Popup` has the same problem as before, but again `Qt.Dialog` + `Qt.BypassWindowManagerHint` works, at least on my platform, LXDE